# Text verification case sensitive on macOS Robot Framework?

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-pythonremoteserver

For example

We need to validate UI Text "SUMMARY PAGE" when we execute script on Windows for getText it will return "SUMMARY PAGE" but same script executed on macOS it will return "Summary Page" and test fail on macOS terminal.

Using Python / robot-framework / issue is on macOS safari browser

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what libraries you are using, or where from is the keyword `getText`.

Also it would be helpful to have a small reproducible example, for us to try.

Your site/application under test, may have some condition that changes output to ALL CAPS depending on the operating system (or browsers).